# gnuplot Data File with Multiple Datasets and High/Low Error Bars

Tags: gnuplot

I haven't used gnu plot before, but after googling around, I can't seem to figure out how to format my data file.

I have multiple datasets and each of these datasets has its own Yhigh and Ylow values. I wish to plot these 3 datasets on the same graph.

```
#X    Y          Yhigh     Ylow  
8    12181.0375  13198.4   11630.5
16   6096.362708 6500.86   4660.34
32   3086.159688 3282.08   2607.13
64   1668.613958 1963.03   1106.13
128  795.7439583 3929.95   554.027
192  486.0394774 614.181   362.243
```

I have 2 more datasets which I want to plot on the same graph. X values are the same. Y values different. However, the approximate Y-range will be similar (so the graph would not look that odd).

I read that, for multiple Y values, you can use:

```
#X    Y1    Y2    Y3
```

in your .dat file and then when plotting, separate as:

```
gnuplot> plot "test.dat" using 1:2 with lines,\
"test.dat" using 1:3 with lines
```

However, I am unsure how to do this when Y1 has Y1_high and Y1_low values, Y2 has Y2_high and Y2_low values, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think perhaps my question was confusing. It was not about reformatting the dataset, but instead, I was asking how you plot multiple sets of data that have the same x-axis values.

I ended up solving my problem by following one of my proposed answers. Data of the format:

```
#X  Y1  Y1_high Y1_low  Y2 Y2_high Y2_low  Y3 Y3_high Y3_low
```

I was then able to plot lines and their associated error bars as follows:

```
plot "mydata.dat" using 1:2 with lines, "mydata.dat" using 1:2:3:4 with error bars,\
"mydata.dat" using 1:5 with lines, "mydata.dat" using 1:5:6:7 with error bars
```

[etc for Y3 values]

Answer (score 1):

The 'natural' formatting of a gnuplot data file would to separate the values with white spaces and without the braces:

```
X Y1 Y2 Y3
```

Now you just need

```
set style data lines
plot 'test.data' using 1:2, '' using 1:3
```

If you have commas as separators you must use

```
set datafile separator ','
```

to plot them correctly. Finally, using your format would work with an explicit format after the `using` statement:

```
plot 'test.dat' using 1:2 '(%lf,%lf,%lf,%lf)'
```

But that is not as flexible as it may seem, because the only allowed formatter is `%lf`.

Answer (score 1):

Christoph has suggested how you should reformat your data. You could do this using awk:

```
awk -F'[(),]' '{$1=$1}1' test.data > new.data
```

This takes your original data and splits it on parentheses and commas. `$1=$1` forces awk to touch the data, so the format of the line is altered. The `1` at the end is just shorthand telling awk to print the line.

Your output then becomes:

```
 X     Y       Yhigh   Ylow   
 8 12181.0375 13198.4 11630.5 
 16 6096.362708 6500.86 4660.34 
 32 3086.159688 3282.08 2607.13 
 64 1668.613958 1963.03 1106.13 
 128 795.7439583 3929.95 554.027 
 192 486.0394774 614.181 362.243
```

Your input can actually be altered using the same approach from within gnuplot:

```
plot "<awk -F'[(),]' '{$1=$1}1' test.data" every ::1
```

The `every ::1` is used to skip the first line. Slightly shorter would be to swap the `1` at the end of the awk line for `NR>1` which evaluates to `1` for every line after the first:

```
plot "<awk -F'[(),]' '{$1=$1}NR>1' test.data"
```